# Getting record based on date range

Tags: oracle

I have table with member enrollment info on different dates. I need a query to find the member info.

Given a date it will check if user enroll in that date or not

- if yes it return that date
- if no it return latest enrollment row.

There is an additional status column in result which show if member is enrolled or not as of today. I am computing it using CASE statement.

Here a query I have so far to display latest for each member. I need help to modify/in cooperate so that it return me true condition also.

```
select *
from (
  select id, member_id, enroll_date, end_date,
    CASE 
      WHEN sysdate between enroll_date and end_date THEN 'Active'
      ELSE 'Inactive'
    END
    Status,
    row_number() over (partition by member_id order by enroll_date desc) rn
  from myView
)where rn = 1
```

Table structure

```
ID   MEMBER_ID   ENROLL_DATE   END_DATE
01   123456789   01-JAN-13     31-DEC-13
02   123456789   01-JAN-06     31-DEC-06
03   123456789   01-JAN-11     31-DEC-11
04   987654321   01-JAN-08     31-DEC-12
05   987654321   01-FEB-13     31-DEC-99
06   987654321   01-JAN-13     31-JAN-13
```

I want to get info and status of the member based on input date.

For example

a) If input date is 2005/1/1 then it should give me 01 and 05

```
01   123456789   01-JAN-13     31-DEC-13     Inactive
05   987654321   01-FEB-13     31-DEC-99     Active
```

b) If input is 2006/1/1 then it should give me 02 and 05

```
02   123456789   01-JAN-06     31-DEC-06     Inactive
05   987654321   01-FEB-13     31-DEC-99     Active
```

c) If input is 2013/1/1 then it should give me 01 and 06

```
01   123456789   01-JAN-13     31-DEC-13     Inactive
06   987654321   01-JAN-13     31-JAN-13     Inactive
```

d) If input is 2014/1/1 then it should give me 01 and 05

```
01   123456789   01-JAN-13     31-DEC-13     Inactive
05   987654321   01-FEB-13     31-DEC-99     Active
```

Comment: Don't understand your dates. 99 1999 or 2099?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from (
  select id, member_id, enroll_date, end_date,
    CASE 
      WHEN sysdate between enroll_date and end_date THEN 'Active'
      ELSE 'Inactive'
    END
    Status,
    row_number() over (partition by member_id 
                       order by case when :input_date between enroll_date and end_date 
                                then 1 else 2 end, enroll_date desc) rn
  from myView
)where rn = 1
```

This is a tricky order which lets you assign rn=1 for a row which fits the given date. Otherwise the row with max enrol date is assigned rn=1

```
order by case when :input_date between enroll_date and end_date 
         then 1 else 2 end, enroll_date desc
```

Comment: Where is input date param?